# Simplest way to protect a static website using oauth2

Tags: python, node.js, oauth-2.0, python-sphinx

I'd like to secure my company documentation (static website created with Sphinx) with the google oauth2.

What is the easiest way to achieve this ? I precise I'm more a python and javascript guy. Ideas or libraries names would be welcome !

Thanks !

Comment: you mean authenticate with google? why not just use htaccess basic auth? ... I dont think there is an easy way to do what you are asking ...

Comment: basically you would have to create a webapp to serve your documentation ... see http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/web/quickstart.html#authentication ... oauth-2.0 is very easy to implement in general however ... so I would first look over that link and get your website to be a Flask app

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving the website using the Apache webserver (or use Apache as a reverse proxy in front of that content) you can use [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc) version 1.7.2 with its support for validation of Google's access tokens. The [configuration](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc#access-control-with-google-oauth-20) would look like:

```
OIDCOAuthIntrospectionEndpoint https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo
OIDCOAuthIntrospectionTokenParamName access_token
OIDCOAuthRemoteUserClaim user_id

<Location /static/>
    Authtype oauth20
    # require specific claims to be present in the JSON
    # response returned from the token info endpoint
    Require claim issued_to:<client_id>
</Location>
```